How do I solve this jdk error message while trying to build an android app on IntelliJ using Flutter?
I'm new to Flutter Dev and I am trying to make my first app using IntelliJ.
However I keep getting this error message incessantly when I try to run my app on an Android phone and also an Android emulator.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution
failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. >
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.


Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes
{artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image,
org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. >
Execution failed for JdkImageTransform:
C:\Users\username.jdks\openjdk-22.0.2\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.


Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android
Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path
C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod
--add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage
--disable-plugin system-modules} * Try: >
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. >  Run with
--info or --debug option to get more log output. >  Run with --scan to get full insights. >
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I have tried installing jdk versions 11 and 17 and it still doesn't help. I have ran flutter doctor in the terminal and it shows no errors. I have tried all the troubleshooting but it still doesn't help.
The app builds and runs on Windows desktop and Chrome browser perfectly fine.
Can someone help me fix this please?
